# Angular-material: Remove dots in discrete md-slider

Tags: angularjs, slider, angular-material

While using md-slider from angular-material, if the range of max and min is less, then the slider is looking fine:
[image]

However if the range of value is wide (1-100) then the pink line of the slider is getting overlapped by grey dots:
[image]

Is there a way to remove these grey dots from md-slider in md-discrete mode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular-material discrete md-slider dots can be removed using the following CSS snippet

```
.md-track-ticks canvas { display: none; }
```

Comment: It is proper answer, do you want me to provide a fiddle link for the answer?

Comment: It's far better without the "try this". Be self-confident in your answer ;) .

Comment: haha sure. I was sure, i tested the code before posting but just wrote "try this", thanks for the critique though, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was CSS naming issue according to which version.
This works for me. 
Thanks Salal.

```
._md-track-ticks canvas, .md-track-ticks canvas { display: none; }
```